# node-RED-dashboard: How do I download a csv file created with a file output node?

Tags: file, download, export, dashboard, node-red

My aim is to display links to csv files so an end user can download them.

So I created a csv file and saved it using a file output node but I can't find a way to allow the end user to click a link/button to download it. I tried the following flow, but it points to `http://localhost:1880/ui/~/TEST.CSV`:

`[{"id":"3aff08aa.8731d8","type":"inject","z":"a24aefdf.d606e","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":120,"y":100,"wires":[["1541e37c.3072dd"]]},{"id":"1541e37c.3072dd","type":"function","z":"a24aefdf.d606e","name":"","func":"msg.payload = {};\nmsg.payload = {\"col1\": 1, \"col2\": 2};\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":270,"y":100,"wires":[["2d045a05.efbef6"]]},{"id":"12ba838c.dcd18c","type":"file","z":"a24aefdf.d606e","name":"TEST.CSV","filename":"~/TEST.CSV","appendNewline":true,"createDir":true,"overwriteFile":"true","x":570,"y":100,"wires":[]},{"id":"2d045a05.efbef6","type":"csv","z":"a24aefdf.d606e","name":"","sep":",","hdrin":true,"hdrout":true,"multi":"one","ret":"\\n","temp":"col1, col2","x":410,"y":100,"wires":[["12ba838c.dcd18c"]]},{"id":"5a9db6ab.f35b28","type":"http in","z":"a24aefdf.d606e","name":"downloads","url":"/downloads","method":"get","upload":false,"swaggerDoc":"","x":120,"y":160,"wires":[["7291d925.cfc9b8","ccef1ce3.900b8"]]},{"id":"7291d925.cfc9b8","type":"debug","z":"a24aefdf.d606e","name":"","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"false","x":140,"y":240,"wires":[]},{"id":"1916b0d1.3c55ff","type":"http response","z":"a24aefdf.d606e","name":"response","statusCode":"200","headers":{"content-type":"text/plain"},"x":560,"y":160,"wires":[]},{"id":"ccef1ce3.900b8","type":"ui_template","z":"a24aefdf.d606e","group":"a1588fc.a8dc47","name":"","order":0,"width":0,"height":0,"format":"<div ng-bind-html=\"msg.payload\"></div>\n<a href=\"~/TEST.CSV\">Download TEST.CSV</a>","storeOutMessages":true,"fwdInMessages":true,"templateScope":"local","x":420,"y":160,"wires":[["1916b0d1.3c55ff"]]},{"id":"a1588fc.a8dc47","type":"ui_group","z":"","name":"Data Export","tab":"ea941605.788c18","disp":true,"width":"12"},{"id":"ea941605.788c18","type":"ui_tab","z":"","name":"Dashboard","icon":"dashboard","order":1}]`

I expect this is something to do with absolute paths, but I don't know where the node-red web server's root is in the file system...

Any help would be gratefully received.

Cheers,
Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a section in your `settings.js` file, which by default reads:

> ```
> // When httpAdminRoot is used to move the UI to a different root path, the
> // following property can be used to identify a directory of static content
> // that should be served at http://localhost:1880/.
> //httpStatic: '/home/nol/node-red-dashboard/',
> ```

If you have not already done so, uncomment the `httpStatic` line and set a directory path to some absolute location that your node-red server can write to. Then restart node-red, and modify your flow to output the CSV file to this directory. Any files/folders you create under this location can now be served by the node-red express server.

When your node-red server starts, it will print out the absolute path used for serving static files -- for instance, in my project it shows:

```
13 Jan 12:06:45 - [info] Settings file  : C:\NODE\node_red_ui\settings.js
```

**`13 Jan 12:06:45 - [info] HTTP Static    : C:\NODE\node_red_ui\public`**

```
13 Jan 12:06:45 - [info] User directory : C:\NODE\node_red_ui
13 Jan 12:06:45 - [info] Flows file     : C:\NODE\node_red_ui\flows_ENTLAPTOP18.json
13 Jan 12:06:45 - [info] Dashboard using development folder
13 Jan 12:06:45 - [info] Server now running at http://localhost:1880/admin/
13 Jan 12:06:45 - [info] Starting flows
```

So if I create the file `C:\NODE\node_red_ui\public\downloads\test.csv`,

then it can downloaded through the url =>
http://localhost:1880/downloads/test.csv